# how to reference widgets and classes from other screen in kivy python while i am not using kv design

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, screenshot, kivy-language, attributeerror

While I am new to Python. I am making a chat app in `kivy`. I want everytime a user signup. I want to get data from  my firebase data and store it into a `MDlist` of registered users.  while I am trying to do it, I am facing errors as both my widgets are on different screen every time I try to connect both screen it, gives me attribute error as i am not using `kv` design file. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        R=RegisterWindow
        L=LoginWindow
        F=FirstWindow
        M=MassageWindow
    




class RegisterWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        #backgroundimage
        self.image = Image(source='image2.png', width=100, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        #appbarr
        self.tool = MDTopAppBar(title='App Bar')
        self.tool.pos_hint = {'top': 1}
        self.tool.left_action_items = [['arrow-left-bold-box', lambda x: self.screen_transition1()]]
        self.tool.right_action_items = [['arrow-right-bold-box', lambda x: self.screen_transition()]]
        self.add_widget(self.tool)

        #cardview
        self.i2 = MDCard(radius= [12, 30], pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .3},size_hint=(.2,.1),padding= 4)
        self.img2=OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text='image') #allow_stretch=True, )width=100,keep_ratio=False
        self.img3=ImageRightWidget(source='')
        self.i2.add_widget(self.img3)
        self.add_widget(self.i2)

        #textfield
        self.lable= MDLabel(text='Username', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.lable)
        self.username = MDTextFieldRect(multiline=False, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.l2=MDLabel(text='Phone', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .5})
        self.add_widget(self.l2)
        self.password = MDTextFieldRect(input_filter='int',multiline=False, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .5})
        self.add_widget(self.password)
        self.l3=MDLabel(text='Image', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .3})
        self.add_widget(self.l3)
        self.file= MDRaisedButton(text='Upload',size_hint=(.1,.1),pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .3})
        self.file.bind(on_press=self.upload)
        self.add_widget(self.file)


        #Buttonsubmit
        self.btn = MDRaisedButton(text='Register', size_hint=(0.7, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .03})
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.submit)


class LoginWindow(Screen):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            LW=LoginWindow
            #backgroundimage
            self.image = Image(source='image2.png', width=100, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
            self.add_widget(self.image)
            self.tool = MDTopAppBar(title='App Bar')
            self.tool.pos_hint = {'top': 1}
            self.tool.right_action_items = [['arrow-right-bold-box', lambda x:self.screen2()]]
            self.tool.left_action_items = [['arrow-left-bold-box', lambda x: self.screen3()]]
            self.add_widget(self.tool)
            scroll=ScrollView(size_hint=(1,0.9))
            self.list=MDList()
            scroll.add_widget(self.list)

            #chatlist
            
            self.items=ThreeLineIconListItem(text="Name", secondary_text='Massage',on_press=self.ad)
            self.xyz=ImageLeftWidget(source='image1.png')
            self.items.add_widget(self.xyz)
            self.list.add_widget(self.items)
            self.add_widget(scroll)
            self.by1=MDRaisedButton(text="print",size_hint=(0.7, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .03})
            self.by1.bind()

            self.add_widget(self.by1)
```